# A Framework to remind the user that their login is about to expire

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, nuget

Is there a framework that I can implement on a MVC website which will hook into my session and provide a reminder that their login is about to time out?

Ideally I would like to provide a view which would have the popup message on which can be configured.

Also how would it work across browser tabs? If there were two tabs and you logged out on one then the session would be finished on the second tab. Is there a way of gracefully redirecting the second tab to the login page. For example if on second tab and fire some AJAX to a secured action I then get a fail. Could that redirect to login?

I written something like this in the past but can be time consuming to test etc. and the multi tab issue was tricky.

Ideally I am wanting something to plug in and use and configure.

Answer (score 1):

You will not find required solution out of box.
Step by step you need to implement :
- js side script that will run something like timeout for a time of timeout - 1 min for example. Also you will need sync it with other tabs by using any plugin. and also keep in mind about fact, that every ajax-call or request to server will extend user session.
- logout for all tabs also can be implemented simply by using any js plugin to share data across tabs. all tabs subscribing to logout event and first tab that will detect logout at client side will throw that event.

Something like that...

or you can use SignalR, but it is too massive for that task

Comment: thanks @Nigrimmist. I implemented this before and at the end of the javascript timeout it would make a call the server. If they had logged in (in another tab) then it would have an open session and return that back to the client so that the message could be removed and the counter restarted.